# Why parallel seq scan is not chosen by planner for jsonb type of fields?

Tags: postgresql, performance, parallelism, performance-tuning, postgresql-performance

I have a table with jsonb type of column (filter_data) and I set

```
set force_parallel_mode to true
set max_parallel_workers_per_gather to 8
```

Then I execute

```
explain analyze
select
stream_packet_id
from json_stream_packet_filter
where true
and exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(filter_data->'n48') elem where true and elem->>'tid' in ('12037', '12054', '19613', '110710', '118803', '8980823', '15221109', '15363353', '15384072', '15394611', '15398486', '15413724', '20214099', '20371626', '20925262', '22863147', '22870914', '22879288', '22886660', '22899828', '22912416', '22925004', '23824754', '46076357', '47440226', '47890942', '166390891', '166391968', '166555652', '166605165', '168992530', '169073613', '169102534', '175738876', '175774864', '195274646', '195986282', '198500112', '210996444', '211002625', '211012097', '211016534', '211027299', '272229190'))
and exists
(select 1
from jsonb_array_elements(filter_data->'idnt') elem
where true and elem->>'tid' in ('12037', '12054', '19613', '110710', '118803', '8980823', '15221109', '15363353', '15384072', '15394611', '15398486', '15413724', '20214099', '20371626', '20925262', '22863147', '22870914', '22879288', '22886660', '22899828', '22912416', '22925004', '23824754', '46076357', '47440226', '47890942', '166390891', '166391968', '166555652', '166605165', '168992530', '169073613', '169102534', '175738876', '175774864', '195274646', '195986282', '198500112', '210996444', '211002625', '211012097', '211016534', '211027299', '272229190')
and exists
(select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(elem->'rslts') elem2
where true  and (elem2->>'p')::float between 50.0 and 100.0 and elem2->>'eid' in ('203219647')limit 1
))
```

and no parrallel seq scan is used. So the question is: why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan (formatted text please)

Comment: Why is this so complex? Can't you find a simplier "WTF" to paste here, I mean half of these conditions are just superfluous does `where true and` really make a difference? Do these lists of ids really need to be as long? Does it parallelize if you take out some of the selectivity? It seems like you're not trying *at all.*

Comment: @EvanCarroll - About the `where true and` condition. This is a coding convention that I have long railed against, but is pushed in a number of places for coders. It is useful only when building dynamic SQL **and** the coding is lazy, but it "allows" the building of the dynamic WHERE clauses so that, if no conditions are chosen for any conditions, the WHERE ends up simply as `where true`. Why they don't exclude the `exists` check if no conditions are selected is beyond me, but that's the thought behind it.

Comment: Oh, and I almost forgot - the other reason is so they do not have to decide whether or not to add the word `and` into the clause. Since there is a first "test" already in the WHERE clause, all others need to have an AND added, simplifying coding and making for ugly SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything which can conceivably be parallelized has actually been implemented in parallel.  Sub-plans is one of the things that has not been done yet.

People [are working on this feature](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAA4eK1KN785VajAH%3DHNsCAJdncPavC--8D6QEtxNRr-C9vfE3w%40mail.gmail.com) for version 10 (the next major release), and some preliminary tests suggest it will help with your query.  It is not clear whether that proposed code will make it into v10 or not.  If you want to increase the chances, you can help by reviewing the proposed changes, or compiling it and testing it. It will certainly be more productive than swearing at us is.

You could also try to rewrite the query not to use exists(subquery) in the first place.  This would allow parallel query in v9.6, and might also be faster regardless of whether it is parallel or not.  Something like this works to allow parallel on a reduced set, I don't know what the speed would be on your full query:

```
and filter_data->'n48' @> ANY(ARRAY['[{"tid":12037}]'::jsonb,'[{"tid":4}]'::jsonb]);
```

But I would probably question whether JSONB is the correct format to hold your data in the first place.

Comment: Regarding Postgres 10: There are (unstable!) RPM packages available so it's not even necessary to compile for yourself: https://yum.postgresql.org/news10snapshot-ready-for-testing.php  And there is also a Docker image: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgrpms.git;a=blob;f=docker/README

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but the code has not yet been committed to the v10 source tree, it is only proposed code at this point.  So it wouldn't be in the current RPM.